# jquery animate() interfering with css transition resulting in buggy animation

Tags: jquery, css-transitions, transition

I have an odd problem where jquery animate() seems to be interfering with css transitions. I pinned down the problem to this css transition:

```
 transition: 0.5s;
```

Here the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(
        function() {
            $(".closebtn").click(
                function() {
                    $('#myNav').animate(
                        {
                            'width': '0%'
                        },
                        5000,
                        function() {
                            window.location.href = "blog.html"; //will redirect to your blog page (an ex: blog.html)
                        }
                    );

                }
            );
        }
    )
</script>

<style>
body {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 10%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay:hover {
    width: 20%;
}

.overlay-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 45px;
    font-size: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
  .overlay .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  <a href="#" class="closebtn">&times;</a>
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Fullscreen Overlay Nav Example</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open the fullscreen overlay navigation menu.</p>
<p>In this example, the navigation menu will slide in, from left to right:</p>
<span style="margin-left:200px;font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>

<script>
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {

    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";

   setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.href = "blog.html"; //will redirect to your blog page (an ex: blog.html)
    }, 1.5); //will call the function after 2 secs.

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sezj2tvq/

You click on "Open" and the overlay opens. Click on "X" for closing the overlay. When closing the overlay, the animation is kind of sluggish.

When I remove the css transition, the animation works fine. But, of course, the hover effect has no transition anymore.

On my desktop (Win 7), when clicking "x" for closing the overlay, it somehow strangely counts the width, you can see it in Firefox Code-Inspector. It doesn't count from 100% to 0% (closing the overlay), but it starts at something like width="1600%" or something, counting down to "0%", which results in a strange animation.

Can anyone help?